# EditText is losing focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have a `MyCustomView` (inherits from `Android.Views.View`) which I render myself in its `onDraw` method. It is surrounded by a `ScrollView` to make it scrollable. Furthermore it needs to accept text input. So I put a `EditText` on the page and positioned it outside the visible area so that it is not shown. When the page is opened, the `EditText` gets the focus to show the soft keyboard. So far, so good.

But when the user taps on `MyCustomView`, then the `EditText` loses focus and the soft keyboard vanishes.

I already do

```
setFocusable(false);
setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

in both `MyCustomView` and the `ScrollView`.

And I override `onTouchEvent` in both classes and return true without calling the super method. I want to handle the touch gestures myself anyway. Later on, the only gesture handled by the `ScrollView` is the scrolling.

However, the `EditText` still loses focus when I tap `MyCustomView`.

I only want the keyboard to close, when the user taps the respective down arrow in the soft keyboard. It they tap somewhere on `MyCustomView`, the keyboard should remain shown.

As the down arrow on the keyboard should still work, I cannot simply `requestFocus` whenever the `EditText` loses it.